# Working with two different tables with same structure

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

I have following question: 
I have two tables with same structure in SQL-CE database in my WP7 project.
And I want to dynamically use one of these table depending on some condition. For example:

```cs
[Table]
public class myTable1 : someStructure { }

[Table]
public class myTable2 : someStructure { }

[Table]
public class someStructure
{
    [Column (IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class myDB : DataContext
{
    public myDB() : base("Data Source=isostore:/main.sdf") { }

    public Table<myTable1> myTable1;
    public Table<myTable2> myTable2;
}

public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private void doit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var _myDB = new myDB();
        if (!_myDB.DatabaseExists())
            _myDB.CreateDatabase();

        Table<someStructure> _table;
        if ( SOMECONDITION )
            _table = _myDB.myTable1;
        else
            _table = _myDB.myTable2;

        _table.InsertOnSubmit(new someStructure { Name = "aaa" });

        _myDB.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

I receive an `Unable to create database because mapped class 'databasetest1.myTable1' has zero members.` error on `_myDB.CreateDatabase()` line and warnings that type `someStructure` cannot be converted to `myTable1` and/or `myTable2` type.

What I'm supposed to do to solve this task?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have tried, although I don't have it from the CE guys directly, I've never been able to get a `[Table]` to have a base class with any `[Column]` attributes on it.  You might consider using T4 templates to solve this problem for you by just code-generating the bits you need.

Give this a look and see if it helps. I have not tried it myself, but it looks promising...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/writingdata_services/archive/2012/01/25/new-and-improved-t4-template-for-odata-client-and-local-database.aspx